# A question about symmetry of real random variables.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be a real random variable and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ a real number such that $X$ is centrally symmetric with respect to $x$, i.e., $X-x$ is equally distributed tan $x - X$. My question is whether or not $|X - x|$ is equally distributed than $|x - X|$.

The inverse is false, but this implication i doubt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $X, x \in \mathbb R$, then is it not true that $|X - x| = |x - X|$ identically?

Comment: No, if $|X - x|$ is equally distributed than $|x - X|$, then it could happen that $X - x$ is not equally distributed than $x - X$.

Comment: Not only are $|X-x|$ and $|x-X|$ identically distributed, they are **equal** random variables. You also seem to be having problems with English. What does "A is equally distributed than B" mean? The word "than" doesn't fit there. I am assuming you mean "A and B are identically distributed."

Comment: I also don't see what point you're trying to make in response to heropup's comment. It is true that $|X-x|$ and $|x-X|$ being identically distributed doesn't ensure $X-x$ and $x-X$ are identical, but so what?

Comment: @user13761697 My omission of the word "distributed" was absolutely **deliberate**.  When I say "identically," I literally mean they are IDENTICAL.  Not "distributed."  They are EQUAL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is true for the next reason. Let $X$ and $Y$ two real random variables equally distributed.

By definition of the absolute value, we have that
$$\mathbb{P}(|X|\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(-t\leq X\leq t)$$
for any $t\geq 0$. Then, by hypothesis
$$\mathbb{P}(-t\leq X\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(-t\leq Y\leq t) = \mathbb{P}(|Y|\leq t).$$

The case $t < 0$ it is clear that $\mathbb{P}(|X|\leq t) = 0 = \mathbb{P}(|X|\leq t)$.

Comment: This is true, but you're missing an even bigger point here. Not only is it true that $|X-x|$ and $|x-X|$ are identically distributed, but **they are equal as random variables** (a much stronger statement), and it doesn't even matter if $X$ is symmetric around $x$ or not.

Comment: That's true. Thank you for your comment!!